# Quickly Solved Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

At first, you might find that I'm very quick and animated

Later on, you'll realize I'm just trying to be connected

If you only saw my latter, you might think green

I'm obsessed with a princess, but not the queen

Together though, I can take you to new places

Sometimes you need control, leaving behind no traces

**WHAT AM I?**

**HINT**

> The answer is right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9kbQ.png)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are

> a Hyperlink!

At first, you might find that I'm very quick and animated

> OP: Hyper means quick and animated

Later on, you'll realize I'm just trying to be connected

> Link!  The name... (Clever!)

If you only saw my latter, you might think green

> Link always wears green - looking at him from behind, you'd see mostly green

I'm obsessed with a princess, but not the queen

> Princess Zelda

Together though, I can take you to new places

> OP: A hyperlink can take you to new places such as websites, documents, etc.

Sometimes you need control, leaving behind no traces

> OP: In word and excel, you have to hold the control button and click to activate a hyper link. If you use this method, it leaves behind no traces (no way to track what you clicked)

As for the hint

> OP: The answer is a hyperlink :)

Comment: Damn iiiit....I was close. This has to be it.

Comment: My word was hyperlink but this is correct! +1 and accepted, do you mind if I make a few edits to fit some of the lines better?

Comment: Go for it.  Cool riddle +1

Comment: @BrentHackers thank you :) I think the green and princess lines revealed a bit too much though :P

Answer (score 4):

> It's me, Mario

At first, you might find that I'm very quick and animated

> Mario is a video game character

Later on, you'll realize I'm just trying to be connected

> You need to plugin in your console/computer to play. Hence ... "connect" it.

If you only saw my latter, you might think green

> Luigi is green. Thanks to [n_palum](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51306/quickly-solved-riddle/51308?noredirect=1#comment157264_51308)

I'm obsessed with a princess, but not the queen

> The game's objective is to save the princess

Together though, I can take you to new places

> In order to reach the princess you have to go through various levels

Sometimes you need control, leaving behind no traces

> And you need a console "controller" to play.

Comment: I really like this answer and your logic! However, it's not the answer I was looking for :(

Comment: You can use "If you only saw my latter, you might think green" to be Luigi :)

Comment: @n_palum OMG. It was so obvious and I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Quick, animated:

> princess(may be Snow White)

so I think you are

> a MIRROR.